# A differential problem involving expressing one formula in terms of multiple orders

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question is involving this equation:   $y\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2+2y=0$ ; finding an expression for $\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}$ in terms of $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ , $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and y. It has been a while since I solved a problem like this so please explain if you are kind enough to show the steps required to solve this. I am aware that I should probably isolate the first terms and divide through by $y$ but I have never been strong on differentials and I am not sure how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply differentiate your equation, obtaining
$$
y'y''+yy'''+4y'y''+2y'=0\implies y'''=-\frac{(5y''+2)y'}{y}
$$

Comment: Great, thanks, painfully simple to see the solution now, I blame holiday lag.